# How to melt a dataframe with measured variables and associated standard deviations in two columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a premade dataframe, in which each measured variable features an adjacent column with the standard deviations:

```
df <- 
structure(list(Factor = structure(1:3, .Label = c("K", "L", "M"
), class = "factor"), A = c(52127802.82, 63410325.61, 76455661.87
), SD = c(9124562.98, 21975533.21, 9864019.36), B = c(63752980.62, 
68303447.17, 73250794.15), SD.1 = c(34800000, 22600000, 6090000
), C = c(103512032.04, 65074190.8, 92686982.97), SD.2 = c(23900000, 
20800000, 38300000), D = c(100006463.22, NA, 37406494.3)), .Names = c("Factor", 
"A", "SD", "B", "SD.1", "C", "SD.2", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

(SD.1, SD.2 were auto-renamed; originally they were all called "SD").
I want to melt into long format by factor:

```
library(reshape)
df.melt <- melt(df, id.vars="Factor").
```

However, I would like to have the melted object to keep the SD columns attached to their associated columns:

```
Factor Variable value value.sd
K      A        52127802.82 9124562
```

So, i can call `geom_errorbar(ymin=sd.value, ymax=sd.value)` in `ggplot(df.melt, aes(Factor, value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~variable)`.
Is that possible, even with the different row.names for SD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would drop `df$D` from the dataset because I think this is an error via `df$D <- NULL`:

```
#   Factor        A       SD        B     SD.1         C     SD.2
# 1      K 52127803  9124563 63752981 34800000 103512032 23900000
# 2      L 63410326 21975533 68303447 22600000  65074191 20800000
# 3      M 76455662  9864019 73250794  6090000  92686983 38300000
```

Then, I would rename the columns (this looks more complicated than it is and I encourage feedback/suggestions that would make this part more straightforward) -- the reason I am renaming the columns is so that I can use `separate` and `spread` from the package `tidyr`:

```
names(df)[-1][seq(2, length(names(df)) - 1, 2)] <- paste0(names(df)[-1][seq(1, length(names(df)) - 1, 2)], "-SD")
names(df)[-1][seq(1, length(names(df)) - 1, 2)] <- paste0(names(df)[-1][seq(1, length(names(df)) - 1, 2)], "-measure")
df
#   Factor A-measure     A-SD B-measure     B-SD C-measure     C-SD
# 1      K  52127803  9124563  63752981 34800000 103512032 23900000
# 2      L  63410326 21975533  68303447 22600000  65074191 20800000
# 3      M  76455662  9864019  73250794  6090000  92686983 38300000
```

This enables me to make `df_clean`:

```
df_clean <- df %>%
  gather(measure, value, -Factor) %>%
  separate(measure, c("measure_letter", "temp_var")) %>%
  spread(temp_var, value)

df_clean
#   Factor measure_letter   measure       SD
# 1      K              A  52127803  9124563
# 2      K              B  63752981 34800000
# 3      K              C 103512032 23900000
# 4      L              A  63410326 21975533
# 5      L              B  68303447 22600000
# 6      L              C  65074191 20800000
# 7      M              A  76455662  9864019
# 8      M              B  73250794  6090000
# 9      M              C  92686983 38300000
```

Now that our dataset is clean/tidy, we can plot accordingly:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df_clean, aes(x = Factor, y = measure, fill = Factor)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = measure - SD, ymax = measure + SD)) +
  facet_wrap(~ measure_letter)
```

[image: Plot]